# Unable to knit the Rmarkdown file to pdf

Tags: r, r-markdown

I tried to knit a R-markdown file to Pdf but kept receiving an error.  I have included a screenshot of the error. The r chunk in line 107 is:

```
#means and confidence intervals 

ggplot(data = lizard_means_dataframe, aes(x = dist_pred_nest, y = emmean, colour = dist_pred_nest)) +
  geom_point(size = 2) + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower.CL, ymax = upper.CL), lizard_means_dataframe, width = 0.2) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2") + guides(colour="none") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) + xlab ("Distance to the nest of a predator") + ylab ("Distance to the neighbor lizard territory")
```

[image: Error in R]

What should I do here?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by creating another R-markdown file and setting the output as a pdf document. I could not use the `render` function to specify the output format. I uninstalled Miktek and installed Teklive. Now I'm able to knit my document successfully.